# Cleanup spacing - C++ / Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, coding-style, code-formatting

Is there a built-in feature or available add-on for Visual Studio 2010 that will clean up spacing in C++ code so that annoying blocks like this:

```
RandomVar=RandomList.RandomMethod();
```

will become

```
RandomVar = RandomList.RandomMethod();
```

(Same goes for spacing in loops, etc.)

...or do I need to do this myself with find/replace and regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any plugins for Visual Studio which automatically formats code how I like?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437016/are-there-any-plugins-for-visual-studio-which-automatically-formats-code-how-i-l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-formatting settings for C++ in Eclipse are more extensive than in Visual Studio, so I ended up using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a proper "Solution" but a possible work-around without the need for finding external tools**

- In the "Tools" menu pick "Options..."
- In this dialog navigate to
  "Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting"
- Set the layout options as you
  would like your code to look.
- Click OK.
- Now in a unit with "bad"
  formatting from the menu select "Edit->Advanced->Format document" and the IDE wil reformat the
  document to match your settings.

**For C#, VB etc the "Formating" option has several sub nodes that provide a fine grain of control for the sort of spacing options you ask for.  The list for C/C++ is flat and very limited by comparison. I suspect there is not enough flexability for the layout you want.**

So you probably cannot get the formatting you want directly.  How about...

- Set the spacing rules you want for C++ in the C# settings
- Temporarily adding a C# project to your solution
- adding a class to that
- emptying it.
- paste the C++ in (causing a reformat)
- copy back to the original file
- rinse and repeat
- remove the  temporary C# project

I have to say **this is not pretty**, but given the syntactical similarities between C++ and C# its probably a close match.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but there doesn't seem to be any C++ formatting settings for spacing, and even though C# had more options, that tip didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are looking for Edit->Advanced->Format document. This will re-format your current document according to settings in Tools->Options->Text Editor->c/c++->Formatting.

It's keyboard shortcut Ctrl+E+D in my case.

Comment: Don't have this option, isn't it just for C#? I can format selected code, but the options for C++ aren't as extensive as C#, so this doesn't help.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010 for C++ this option is Edit->Advanced->Format selection, so you should select whole document before formatting it.

Answer (score 0):

Although originally for C code formatting **lint** has been modified to cover C++ and ported to many platforms.

Some lint variants only report inconsistent layout, others can fix it for you.  some are free others paid for versions.

This would be an outside the IDE fix as this is a sperate tool (at least traditionally it is!)

[This wikipeadia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) lists a few possible sources for lint tools

*(this was a footer in my orginal question, but as that posed two solutions I extracted it here so you can accept a specifc answer should you find one apropriate)*

Comment: Wow, a long list. Any tips on which one/s to try out? There is also at least one lint plug-in for VS....

Comment: Sorry no. I live in C# so my C++ is mostly logn remembered stuff from university.  Lint is a old freind from C days on unix where it was part and parcel of the Os along with the C compiler.  So I havent had to pick a windows lint tool myself, hopefully other posters can augment my post with their personal recommendations.